# How can I add the comment box to it

Tags: javascript

I am using blogger. And I want to add the number of comments to my codes. I will share the code I use below. There is a code similar to this and I am adding this too.

**I want to add the number of comments to my codes below. The example I found has the number of comments.**

```
<div id='artikel-terbaru'>
<ol>
<script>
  var jumlahnewpost = 5; //jumlah post yang ingin ditampilkan
  var create = true;
</script>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
function showrecentposts(e) {
    for (var t = 0; t < jumlahnewpost; t++) {
        var r, n = e.feed.entry[t],
            i = n.title.$t;
        if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var l = 0; l < n.link.length; l++)
            if ("alternate" == n.link[l].rel) {
                r = n.link[l].href;
                break
            }
        i = i.link(r), create && document.write("<li>"), document.write(i)
    }
    create && document.write("</li>");
}
//]]>
</script>
<script src='/feeds/posts/summary/-/Mavi?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts'/> 
  </ol>
</div>
```

**Example I found.**

```
function labelthumbs(json) {
    document.write('<ul class="label_with_thumbs">');
    for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
        var posturl;
        if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
                var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
            }
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var thumburl;
        try {
            thumburl = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
        } catch (error) {
            s = entry.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                thumburl = d;
            } else thumburl = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zP87C2q9yog/UVopoHY30SI/AAAAAAAAE5k/AIyPvrpGLn8/s1600/picture_not_available.png';
        }
        var postdate = entry.published.$t;
        var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
        var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
        var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
        var monthnames = new Array();
        monthnames[1] = "Jan";
        monthnames[2] = "Feb";
        monthnames[3] = "Mar";
        monthnames[4] = "Apr";
        monthnames[5] = "May";
        monthnames[6] = "June";
        monthnames[7] = "July";
        monthnames[8] = "Aug";
        monthnames[9] = "Sept";
        monthnames[10] = "Oct";
        monthnames[11] = "Nov";
        monthnames[12] = "Dec";
        document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true)
            document.write('<a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top"><img width="56" height="46" class="label_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '" alt="' + posttitle + '" title="' + posttitle + '"/></a>');
        document.write('<div class="title-label"><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></div>');
        if ("content" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
        } else
        if ("summary" in entry) {
            var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
        } else var postcontent = "";
        var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
        if (showpostsummary == true) {
            if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
                document.write('');
                document.write(postcontent);
                document.write('');
            } else {
                document.write('');
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
                var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                document.write(postcontent + '...');
                document.write('');
            }
        }
        var towrite = '';
        var flag = 0;
        document.write('<br>');
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + '-' + cdyear;
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (showcommentnum == true) {
            if (flag == 1) {
                towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            }
            if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
            if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
            commenttext = '<a class="comment-label" href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
            towrite = towrite + commenttext;
            flag = 1;;
        }
        if (displaymore == true) {
            if (flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            towrite = towrite + '<a class="more-label" href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More »</a>';
            flag = 1;;
        }
        document.write(towrite);
        document.write('</li>');
        if (displayseparator == true)
            if (i != (numposts - 1))
                document.write('');
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
```

Above is the example I found.

Comment: Where are you stuck? There is a bunch of code here, but nothing that suggests what went wrong or what you tried to do besides find code.

Comment: I think these are the codes that give the number of comments. I WANT TO ADD THESE CODES TO THE CODE I GIVEN

Comment: if (showcommentnum == true) {
            if (flag == 1) {
                towrite = towrite + ' | ';
            }
            if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
            if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
            commenttext = '<a class="comment-label" href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
            towrite = towrite + commenttext;
            flag = 1;;
        }

Comment: Again, this is a bunch of code. Is there an error? Still not sure what you tried.

Comment: There is no error, I want to add this to the code I gave at the top

Comment: I think I am not fully understood. I want to add the number of comments to the codes I have given at the top. When I researched, I saw how it called the number of comments in the example codes I gave below. And based on this, I want to add it to my codes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure the question, just simple thought, it may be what do you want, by adding the index i as

```
i = i.link(r), create && document.write("<li>" + i + ". "), document.write(i)
```

Comment: I think I am not fully understood. I want to add the number of comments to the codes I have given at the top. When I researched, I saw how it called the number of comments in the example codes I gave below. And based on this, I want to add it to my codes.

Comment: Gives the titles of the articles